# How add active state to my menu with php or jquery or css?

Tags: php, jquery, css

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="item"><a href="">Home</a>/</li>
                <li class="item"><a href="two">Tab2</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="three">Tab3</a></li>
                 <li class="item"><a href="four">Tab3</a></li>
           </ul>
<div>
```

now, i want to add class='active' to the menu. when the menu is the current page.namely. when i on the home page. the li label is `<li class="item" class="active">` the others are <`li class="item">`. when i on the Tab2 page. the li label is `<li class="item" class="active">`.the others are `<li class="item">`

**PS:** IF I want to add the class="active" to a label, like this `<li class="item"><a href="" class="active">Home</a>/</li>`. how should i do? according to  the **Headshota's** instruction. i got this, but it's too complicated. is there a simple way to get it with php? thank you.

```
<?php
$current = array("","two","three","four");
?>
then 
<li class="item"><a href="" class="<?php if($GET[$current(0)]=="") echo "active"; ?>">Home</a>/</li>
 <li class="item"><a href="two" class="<?php if($GET[$current[1]]=="two") echo "active"; ?>">Tab2</a></li>
     <li class="item"><a href="three" class="<?php if($GET[$current[2]]=="three") echo "active"; ?>">Tab3</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="four" class="<?php if($GET[$current[3]]=="four") echo "active"; ?>">Tab3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will add class to menu when you click on it:

```
$('#nav ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in Jquery you can compare link hrefs with part of the url, but it's not a good practice...

you can have url parameter, for example menu_id

which you'll pass on every request. and check on every menu for appropriate value;

```
<li class="item <?php if($_GET['menu_id']==1){ echo 'active';} ?>">
  <a href="blablabla.php?menu_id=1">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="item <?php if($_GET['menu_id']==2){ echo 'active';} ?>">
  <a href="blablabla.php?menu_id=2">Tab2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: if i want to add the class="active" to the a label? how should i do? i assign the null and one two three four to a variable($current), then in each line <a class="<?php if($_GET['current']==..){ echo 'active';} ?>"... am i right?

Comment: thank you., i am a newbie of php,i have added my code to the quertion. Is the code right?